# getaddrinfo throws exception

Tags: c++, sockets

The above socket call is throwing an exception. Here's the code snippet :

```
if (!getaddrinfo((PCSTR)serverHost.c_str(), (PCSTR)serverPort, &hints, &result))
    return false;
```

Looks like the problem is with the `result struct`.

This is how I defined it - `struct addrinfo *result = NULL`;

I've defined and implemented this exactly as mentioned in the msdn page, but still see issues.

Here's the exception:

> Exception thrown at 0x76406783 (KernelBase.dll) in AnandServer.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000050

My understanding was the `getaddrinfo` function populates the result structure with values.

Any pointers on where the issue could be.

Comment: There shouldn't be any casts in your code.

Comment: @VTT yup, I'm pretty sure it's the cast on `serverPort` that's hiding the real problem

Comment: I'm voting to close this as too vague because you only posted a snippet without all the other context of what all the other symbols used in it are, so readers can only speculate about the possible problem, which is not useful.

Comment: @underscore_d and yet I'm 99% sure I know what his problem is... :p

Comment: Congrats. But I don't think people should post questions *expecting* people to guess correctly like you *probably* did.

Comment: Remove the cast on serverhost.  What error does the compiler give you?  Do not try and shut the compiler up by applying a cast.  Understand what the error is telling you.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the cast on `serverHost` is "correct", albeit superfluous.  It's the one on `serverPort` that's wrong, because AFAICS he's casting the value of a numeric type to `PCSTR`.

Comment: @Alnitak: If `serverHost` is a `char`-based string (ie, `std::string`), casting to `PCSTR` is unnecessary since `c_str()` *already* returns a `PCSTR` (aka `const char*`). If `serverHost` is NOT a `char`-based string, then you shouldn't be using it with `getaaddrinfo()` at all.

Comment: Yes, I meant the `serverPort` parameter.  But my real point is to remove all casts and read and understand the error messages if you get compiler errors, not just cast the errors away.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - can we do away with the cast? This is for win socket. It expects a PCSTR type in this function call.

Comment: @techieChamp -- You were expecting the cast to do a conversion to a string.  Casting is not conversion, plain and simple.

Answer (score 4):

Your use of `result` appears to be correct.

Did you perhaps define `int serverPort = 80` (or some other integer type), instead of as a string?  That would be consistent with you getting an Access Violation trying to read from address `0x00000050` (80 in decimal).

The second parameter of `getaddrinfo()` expects a null-terminated string containing the service name, which can be a port number in textual format.  You need to pass in an actual string, DO NOT simply type-cast an integer to a `char*` pointer.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I defined server port as an int and then cast to PCSTR. I defined it as a string and it worked fine.